# Retrieve particular parts of string from a text file and save it in a new file in MATLAB

Tags: regex, matlab, indexing, printf

I am trying to retrieve particular parts of a string in a text file such as below and i would like to save them in a text file in MATLAB

Original text file

```
D 1m8ea_    1m8e    A:  d.174.1.1   74583   cl=53931,cf=56511,sf=56512,fa=56513,dm=56514,sp=56515,px=74583
D 1m8eb_    1m8e    B:  d.174.1.1   74584   cl=53931,cf=56511,sf=56512,fa=56513,dm=56514,sp=56515,px=74584
D 3e7ia1    3e7i    A:77-496    d.174.1.1   158052  cl=53931,cf=56511,sf=56512,fa=56513,dm=56514,sp=56515,px=158052
D 3e7ib1    3e7i    B:77-496    d.174.1.1   158053  cl=53931,cf=56511,sf=56512,fa=56513,dm=56514,sp=56515,px=158053
D 2bhja1    2bhj    A:77-497    d.174.1.1   128533  cl=53931,cf=56511,sf=56512,fa=56513,dm=56514,sp=56515,px=128533
```

So basically, I would like to retrieve the pdbcodes id which are labeled as `"1m8e"`, chainid labeled as `"A"` the Start values which is `"77"` and stop values which is `"496"` and i would like all of these values to be saved inside of a fprintf statment.

Is there some kind of method is which i can use in RegExp stating which index its all starting at and retrieve those strings based on the position in the text file for each line?

In the end, all i want to have in the fprinf statement is `1m8e, A, 77, 496`.

So far i have two `fopen` function which reads a file and one that writes to a new file and to read each line by line, also a `fprintf` statment:

```
pdbcode = '';
chainid = '';
start = '';
stop = '';
fin = fopen('dir.cla.scop.txt_1.75.txt', 'r');
fout = fopen('output_scop.txt', 'w');
% TODO: Add error check!
while true
    line = fgetl(fin); % Get the next line from the file
    if ~ischar(line)
        % End of file
        break;
    end

           % Print result into output_cath.txt file

           fprintf(fout, 'INSERT INTO cath_domains (scop_pdbcode, scop_chainid, scopbegin, scopend) VALUES("%s", %s, %s, %s);\n', pdbcode, chainid, start, stop);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to [strsplit](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4615-split-delimiter-separated-strings-into-a-matrix/content/strsplit.m) on whitespace, get the third ("1m8e") and fourth elements ("A:77-496"), then repeat the process on the fourth element using ":" as the split character, and then again on the second of those two arguments using "-" as the split character. That's one approach. For example, you could do:

```
% split on space and tab, and ignore empty tokens
tokens = strsplit(line, ' \t', true);
pdbcode = tokens(3);
% split fourth token from previous split on colon
tokens = strsplit(tokens(4), ':');
chainid = tokens(1);
% split second token from previous split on dash
tokens = strsplit(tokens(2), '-');
start = tokens(1);
stop = tokens(2);
```

If you really wanted to use [regular expressions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f0-42649.html), you could try the following

```
pattern = '\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)\s+([A-Za-z]+):([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)';
[mat tok] = regexp(line, pattern, 'match', 'tokens');
pdbcode = cell2mat(tok)(1);
chainid = cell2mat(tok)(2);
start = cell2mat(tok)(3);
stop = cell2mat(tok)(4);
```

Comment: if i would like to use split, don't i need to define the name of the text file such as this : `split('_/', 'fin')` , where `fin` represents the file that i have open to read from?

Also, i tried using the method above with the Regexp and it doesnt work. It prints out empty strings instead. Please advise.

Comment: error in using the split function : `??? Undefined function or method 'split' for input arguments of type 'char'.` Please advise.

Comment: Sorry. Evidently, split has been deprecated. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: `??? Undefined function or method 'strsplit' for input arguments of type 'char'.` I am confused with this syntax error. I have tried just executing the entire code in the command window and it still gave the error. Please advise.

Comment: Hmm. What version of Matlab are you using?

Comment: Version 7.11.0 R2010b. Does it matter in terms of the version?

Comment: It does when some functions no longer work. I'm actually using Octave (which has `strsplit` built in, but is usually very similar). If you put this code in your Matlab path, you should be able to use `strsplit`: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4615-split-delimiter-separated-strings-into-a-matrix/content/strsplit.m